# jspsych 'instructions' block not evaluating variable

Tags: javascript, jspsych

I am trying to do a simple evaluation for an `instructions` type block in jsypscyh. Whenever, I input a variable into my `return_essay` function, my instructions page won't load correctly (shown below). However, if I insert a string or integer *directly* then the page loads correctly.

How can I get the `instructions` to evaluate my variables?

```js
function return_essay(input) {
      return ['<p>You wrote: <br>' + input + '</p>']
}

var show_writing = {
  on_load: function() {
    var zzz = 2;
  },
  type: 'instructions',
  pages: return_essay(zzz),
  show_clickable_nav: false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the page was loading with a static reference. Solution is to update the page directly on load:

```js
function return_essay(input) {
      return ['<p>You wrote: <br>' + input + '</p>']
}

var show_writing = {
  on_load: function(trial) {
    var zzz = 2;
    trial.pages = return_essay(zzz);
  },
  type: 'instructions',
  pages: return_essay(zzz),
  show_clickable_nav: false
}
```